# How to make webpage occupy whole screen irrespcive of its content size

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a webpage using JQuryMobile.  below is my sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Insert Page Title Here</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Insert Content Here</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, my page is not occupying the whole screen , It is spawning upto the content that It has.
I want it occupy/expand the whole screen irrespective of its contents.

Please let me know how to do that in above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't use **data-role="main"**, it is **data-role="content"**, you should also remove **class="ui-content"**, it is automatically added with **data-role="content"**. I am not telling this out of my but, some jQuery Mobile features will not work without **data-role="content"**.

Next thing, before you can change page dimensions you need to understand how jQuery Mobile pages work. Footer and header are fixed with fixed height values. Content is on the other hand stretchable so it will resize according to its inner content, it will **NEVER** automatically resize to take rest of available space, left after footer and header.

There are two available solutions two your problem, one is CSS based and second one is JavaScript based.

### CSS solution:

```
.ui-content {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    top : 40px !important; 
    right : 0;
    bottom : 40px !important; 
    left : 0 !important;    
}
```

40px is here because of header and footer, set it to 0 if you don't need them.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/hJVuM/

#### JavaScript solution

```
function getRealContentHeight() {
    var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();
 
    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    }
    return content_height;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5Qu6P/

Ream more about this topic **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/solution-to-jquery-mobile-page-content-empty-space-height-problem/)**.

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML:

```
<div id="full-size">
  Your contents go here
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
html,body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; }
#full-size{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden; /* or overflow:auto; if you want scrollbars */
```

Just make necessary changes to the class names to make it compatible with your one